# Synchronizing on entire object v/s synchronizing on particular field of an object - which is a better approach

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

While working on a Producer Consumer problem I stumbled upon a scenario wherein I can synchronize on the field "sharedLinkedList" or on the entire object "this" of class "SharedObject".
"sharedLinkedList" is the field the Producer and Consumer threads are going to work on.

Please find a snippet of the class with the Produce method:-

```
 public class SharedObject {
        LinkedList<Integer> sharedLinkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        int capacity = 5;


        public void produce() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (sharedLinkedList) {// Alternately synchronized(this)

                    try {
                        while(sharedLinkedList.size() == capacity){

                            sharedLinkedList.wait();//Alternately this.wait()
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    sharedLinkedList.add(123);
                    sharedLinkedList.notify();//Alternately this.notify
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Both the approaches work.

*1. Synchronizing on the field "sharedLinkedList"*
*2. Synchronizing on the entire object (put as a comment in the code snippet).*

Which is a better approach and why?

Answer (score 1):

With the amount of code you show, both approaches are equivalent. That doesn't mean they are equivalent under all circumstances.

`synchronized(x)` set the lock on `x`, so in general, you should synchronize using an object common to all threads using shared resources. If threads use a single common resource (such as the list), then synchronizing on that list works. If threads share more than one resource, you have to synchronize on a separate object to control access to those shared resources. This can be an object, or `this` depending on the context.

`synchronized(this)` also prevents mutual exclusion among the methods of a class, so that, or synchronized methods are useful if object state needs to be modified in a thread safe manner.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have mentioned in the last paragraph.

Comment: If multiple threads call the same object with `synchronized(this)` blocks, those threads will enter the synchronized block one by one. Because of this, such synchronized blocks are useful if instance variables are to be modified in a thread-safe manner.